# Azure CloudBlockBlob.DownloadTextAsync() in asp.net Web API project never returns but same works in console application

Tags: asp.net-web-api, async-await, azure-blob-storage

I've created one Asp.Net Web API project which uses Azure CloudBlockBlob to download some text asynchronous, but the call never returns.

I tried to run the same code in Console App and it works fine.

Following is the code which has issue:-

```
public async Task<string> DownloadTextAsync(IBlobRef blobRef, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var container = this.GetContainerReference(blobRef);
        try
        {
            this.Logger.Log("Downloading " + blobRef.BlobName);
            return await container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobRef.BlobName).DownloadTextAsync();
        }
        catch (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException e)
        {
            if (e.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode == 404)
                return null;
            Console.WriteLine("Error reading " + blobRef.BlobName + " " + e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This same code if I run in console application or asp.net web form application then it runs perfectly fine.

Kindly help if I'm doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost certainly calling `Task<T>.Result` or `Task.Wait` further up your call stack. This causes a [common deadlock issue that I describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

The reason it deadlocks is because `await` (by default) will capture the current "context" - in this case, an ASP.NET request context. Then, when the operation completes, it will resume the `async` method within that context. However, the ASP.NET request context will only allow one thread in at a time. So, if there's a thread *blocked* in the ASP.NET request context (e.g., by calling `Task.Wait`), then the `async` method cannot resume executing when the `await` completes.

It doesn't deadlock in a Console app because Console apps do not have a "context". In this case, the `async` method resumes on a thread pool thread.

To resolve this issue, replace any calls to `Result` or `Wait` with `await`, and allow `async` to grow through your code. For more information, see [my MSDN article on async best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I tried with Task.ConfigureAwait(false) and then it worked like charm.

Comment: Using `ConfigureAwait(false)` with `Result`/`Wait` is not ideal on ASP.NET. You should use `await` instead.

Comment: Yes I removed all .Result and using await with .ConfigureAwait(false). Thanks